# Forbid insert into table on certain conditions

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, triggers, insert-into

I have a SQL Server 2008 database. There are three terminals connected to it (A, B, C). There is a table `SampleTable` in the database, which reacts to any terminal activity. Every time there is some activity on any terminal, logged on to this DB, the new row is inserted into `SampleTable`.

I want to redirect traffic from one (C) of the three terminals to write to table RealTable and not SampleTable, but I have to do this on DB layer since services that write terminal activity to DB are in Black Box.

I already have some triggers working on `SampleTable` with the redirecting logic, but the problem is that rows are still being inserted into `SampleTable`.

What is the cleanest solution for this. I am certain that deleting rows in an inserting trigger is bad, bad, bad.

Please help.

**Edit:**

Our current logic is something like this (this is pseudo code):

```
ALTER TRIGGER DiffByTerminal
 ON SampleTable
AFTER INSERT
AS
DECLARE @ActionCode VARCHAR(3), 
    @ActionTime DATETIME,
    @TerminalId INT

  SELECT @ActionCode = ins.ActionCode, 
     @ActionTime = ins.ActionTime, 
     @TerminalId = ins.TerminalId
  FROM inserted ins

IF(@TerminalId = 'C')
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO RealTable 
    (   
         ...
    )
    VALUES
    (
         @ActionCode, 
         @ActionTime, 
         @TerminalId
    )
END
```

Comment: What is the trigger? The cleanest is probably to insert via a stored procedure so you have a nice abstracted place to add additional logic

Comment: What is your existing logic?  This sounds like a perfect use for an `INSTEAD OF` trigger

Comment: We can't change the logic for row inserting so it needs to be a trigger or something like a trigger.
@JNK Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Your after trigger doesn't "intercept" anything. It also assumes that all insert operations are single-row. You should try a multi-row insert and see how it breaks.

Comment: @Aaron We tried multi-insert on various occasions and it worked perfectly.

Comment: That's not possible. If you insert two rows into SampleTable (e.g. `INSERT ... SELECT something UNION ALL SELECT something else`, the above trigger code will only insert one arbitrary row into RealTable.

Comment: @Aron I get your point and you are right but the code example you specified is impossible in any of our scenarios. If there are more than one insertions into this table it is again done row by row. That is why I said that this work. But you are totally right.

Comment: @nzic still a really dangerous thing to rely on. Tomorrow someone might write a new method that doesn't blindly observe this row-by-row requirement (which is also inefficient), and of course you can't stop anyone from bypassing your application in the first place and writing their own ad-hoc insert.

Comment: @Aaron totally true 1up from me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to "intercept" something before a row gets inserted into a table, you need an `INSTEAD OF` trigger, not an `AFTER` trigger. So you can drop your existing trigger (which also included flawed logic that assumed all inserts would be single-row) and create this `INSTEAD OF` trigger instead:

```
DROP TRIGGER DiffByTerminal;
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.DiffByTerminal
 ON dbo.SampleTable
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT dbo.RealTable(...) SELECT ActionCode, ActionTime, TerminalID
    FROM inserted
    WHERE TerminalID = 'C';

  INSERT dbo.SampleTable(...) SELECT ActionCode, ActionTime, TerminalID
    FROM inserted
    WHERE TerminalID <> 'C';
END
GO
```

This will handle single-row inserts and multi-row inserts consisting of (a) only C (b) only non-C and (c) a mix.

Comment: Ok please give me some time to test this, but just looking at it seems like a perfect solution

Comment: Seems everything works fine. Since there are some other triggers defined for this table (SampleTable) I suppose that any 'AFTER INSERT trigger' will happen after the row is actually inserted into SampleTable filtered by 'INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger'. Can you please confirm?

Comment: Yes, an AFTER trigger fires AFTER the row has been inserted. You can undo it with a rollback of course, but this will also undo anything else that the INSTEAD OF trigger(s) have done. Why do you need multiple triggers?

Comment: To be quite honest we are using multiple triggers for no other reason than very different things that they represent. Activities that happen on our terminals can vary a lot and influence different tables.
Is this bad architecture?

Comment: @nzic it really depends. You could also write 15 different stored procedures based on input parameters, but you don't have to. It all depends on whether you like maintaining one object or a bunch.

Comment: I come from OOP background so I think that explains a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest solution for you is INSTEAD OF trigger. Simply stating, it's trigger that "fires" on very action you decide and lets you "override" the default behavior of the action.

You can override the INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE statements for specific table/view (you use it a lot with views that combine data from different tables and you want make the view insert-able) using INSTEAD OF trigger, where you can put your logic. inside the trigger you can then call again to INSERT when it's appropriate, and you don't have to worry about recursion - INSTEAD OF triggers won't apply on statements from inside the trigger code itself.

Enjoy.

Comment: Sry ... not question but answer